pass columns to join with ... and defused expressions in R
I'm writing a function where I need to pass in a series of columns as the join columns between two tables with the ... input to my function.
library(tidyverse)

dat <- diamonds |> head(10)

test_fn <- function(...){

  dat1 <- dat
  dat2 <- dat
  
  cols <- enquos(...)
  col_names <- deparse(cols)

  

  left_join(
    dat1
    ,dat2
    ,by=join_by(
      !!!col_names
    )
    ,relationship="many-to-many"
  )


}

Ideally I would use the following inputs test_fn(cut,carat,clarity) and it would pass a column that joins the tables by cut, carat and clarity.

left_join(dat1, dat2, by=join_by(...), relationship="many-to-many")?

I feel like I tried that but apparently not ! thank you

The suggestion by @Jon Spring seems to work. An alternative might be to create a function modeled on the *_join() functions with an explicit by argument.
library(tidyverse)

dat <- diamonds |> head(10)

self_join <- function(df, ...) {
  
  df |>
    left_join(df, by = join_by(...),
              relationship = "many-to-many")
}

dat |>
  self_join(cut, carat, clarity)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 17
#>    carat cut   color.x clarity depth.x table.x price.x   x.x   y.x   z.x color.y
#>    <dbl> <ord> <ord>   <ord>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <ord>  
#>  1  0.23 Ideal E       SI2        61.5      55     326  3.95  3.98  2.43 E      
#>  2  0.21 Prem… E       SI1        59.8      61     326  3.89  3.84  2.31 E      
#>  3  0.23 Good  E       VS1        56.9      65     327  4.05  4.07  2.31 E      
#>  4  0.29 Prem… I       VS2        62.4      58     334  4.2   4.23  2.63 I      
#>  5  0.31 Good  J       SI2        63.3      58     335  4.34  4.35  2.75 J      
#>  6  0.24 Very… J       VVS2       62.8      57     336  3.94  3.96  2.48 J      
#>  7  0.24 Very… I       VVS1       62.3      57     336  3.95  3.98  2.47 I      
#>  8  0.26 Very… H       SI1        61.9      55     337  4.07  4.11  2.53 H      
#>  9  0.22 Fair  E       VS2        65.1      61     337  3.87  3.78  2.49 E      
#> 10  0.23 Very… H       VS1        59.4      61     338  4     4.05  2.39 H      
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: depth.y <dbl>, table.y <dbl>, price.y <int>, x.y <dbl>,
#> #   y.y <dbl>, z.y <dbl>

self_join_alt <- function(df, by = NULL) {
  
  df |>
    left_join(df, by = by,
              relationship = "many-to-many")
}

dat |>
  self_join_alt(by = join_by(cut, carat, clarity))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 17
#>    carat cut   color.x clarity depth.x table.x price.x   x.x   y.x   z.x color.y
#>    <dbl> <ord> <ord>   <ord>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <ord>  
#>  1  0.23 Ideal E       SI2        61.5      55     326  3.95  3.98  2.43 E      
#>  2  0.21 Prem… E       SI1        59.8      61     326  3.89  3.84  2.31 E      
#>  3  0.23 Good  E       VS1        56.9      65     327  4.05  4.07  2.31 E      
#>  4  0.29 Prem… I       VS2        62.4      58     334  4.2   4.23  2.63 I      
#>  5  0.31 Good  J       SI2        63.3      58     335  4.34  4.35  2.75 J      
#>  6  0.24 Very… J       VVS2       62.8      57     336  3.94  3.96  2.48 J      
#>  7  0.24 Very… I       VVS1       62.3      57     336  3.95  3.98  2.47 I      
#>  8  0.26 Very… H       SI1        61.9      55     337  4.07  4.11  2.53 H      
#>  9  0.22 Fair  E       VS2        65.1      61     337  3.87  3.78  2.49 E      
#> 10  0.23 Very… H       VS1        59.4      61     338  4     4.05  2.39 H      
#> # ℹ 6 more variables: depth.y <dbl>, table.y <dbl>, price.y <int>, x.y <dbl>,
#> #   y.y <dbl>, z.y <dbl>

Created on 2024-08-11 with reprex v2.1.1
